# Detecting Ctrl+L

Tags: python, signals

I've found a few examples of detecting special keyboard commands such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, but I'd like to detect <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>and handle it similar to this:

```
def ctrl_c():
   ...

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, ctrl_c)
```

I'm targeting Linux terminal only. No GUI and cross-platform solution is not needed.

Comment: can you be a bit more specific, is this global key detection? is it GUI related? if so which GUI toolkit etc..

Comment: @JamesKent sorry should have specified, no GUI, Linux terminal only (portable solution would be nice but not required). I just want to detect CTRL+L similar to how the given code sample detects CTRL+C

Comment: can't promise it'll work (on a windows terminal right now) but you can try looking at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/597773/shell-scripting-bash-how-to-detect-altn-keystroke

Comment: although reading a bit more, i think that may be doing a global hook which may not be what you want...

Comment: Technically, you don't detect control-C; you detect the signal that the terminal generates when *it* sees control-C. By default, the terminal doesn't do anything for control-L.

Comment: @chepner Does that mean I can't catch it? Also in my terminal CTRL+L will clear the screen if I'm at a prompt (some applications such a `mongo` shell also clear the screen on CTRL+L, I'm trying to implement the same)

Comment: That's not a signal; Control-L generates ASCII 0x0c (form feed), which is "displayed" by clearing the screen.

Comment: If this is a console thing, can't you use [`getch()`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/getch) to catch your input, then your script can either display it for a normal keypress, or do something else on `CTRL+L`

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments, I don't think that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> generates a signal that can be caught, but this code will get all key-presses at the terminal, and either simply echo them if a normal character or react for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> You could implement something similar, maybe?

```
import getch
import sys
while True:
    char = getch.getch()
    if ord(char) == 3:
        sys.exit()
    elif ord(char) == 12:
        print 'Ctrl + L Pressed!'
    else:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
```

Caveat, I tested this on a Windows box using `msvcrt` as I don't have a Linux system to hand, it should work OK though.